# Options binding: select list does not reflect value of bound object

Tags: knockout.js

I'm using the options binding on a select list used in a jQuery template:

```
<select data-bind="options: contactsViewModel.emailTypes, optionsText: 'Value', value: EmailType"></select>
```

The template is called with a knockout foreach for multiple email addresses.

EmailTypes is a list of emailtype objects
The email object consist of the Value property which contains the string value of the email address, an Id property which contains a Guid id and an email type property which contains the emailtype object.

The emailtype object consists of the Value property which contains the name of the email type and a guid id.

The dropdown is correctly filled with the available email types, but the dropdown doesn't select the right item. It doesn't reflect the value of the object bound to it.

EDIT:
The template with the showed select line is getting called by this:
tbody data-bind="template: { name: 'emailTemplate', foreach: contactsViewModel.selectedContactEmails }">

selectedContactEmails is an observableArray filled with email objects, looking like this in Json:

```
{"EmailType":{"Value":"Home","Id":"191e8a64-8110-493c-b443-3063ff3a852a"},"ParentId":"191e8a64-8110-493c-b443-3063ff3a852c","Parent":null,"Value":"jan@jan.com","Id":"a7aae8fd-6ca3-49ae-b529-124d37a148ca"}
```

The properties of these objects are converted to observables using the mapping plugin.

emailTypes is an observableArray filled with EmailType objects:

```
{"Value":"Home","Id":"191e8a64-8110-493c-b443-3063ff3a852a"}
```

Comment: can you show us your View Model?

Comment: The viewmodel is rather big, so I've outlined the significant observables and the object structure. Hope you can help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The dropdown doesn't select the bounded value because the dropdown doesn't even know which attribute is it bounded to. You'll need to specify the `selectedOptions` attribute in your data binding.

The `options` attribute tells drop down about the array it holds.

The `optionsText` attribute tells drop down which property is used to display for each array item.

The `optionsValue` attribute tells dropdown which property is used for option value.

How will the dropdown know which value is it binded to?

Use [selected options](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/selectedOptions-binding.html)

Comment: Thanks. In my dropdown, the user has to select one value. From the documentation I understand I have to use "value" in that case instead of "selectedOptions". I've tried selectedOptions, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I don't see a select list in this example.

Comment: sorry this is the correct link > http://jsfiddle.net/ucAUC/3/ (no i am not drunk :P )

Comment: :-) Yep, that works. But why doesn't it work if I replace the viewModel with this: var eagle = {
    EmailType: ko.observable({"Value":"School","Id":"491e8a64-8110-493c-b443-3063ff3a852a"})
};

Comment: because they are not the same object. try running `alert (emailTypes[2] == {"Value":"School","Id":"491e8a64-8110-493c-b443-3063ff3a852a"});` Javascript compares object using the references and I certainly assume Knockout is doing the same. The correct way for you is to get the `Id` through JSON (instead of getting the whole object) and then find the object from `emailTypes` using the `Id` (why pass the whole object over the wire anyways when you already have it on client?)

Comment: Aha.. great suggestion. Now for the final piece of the puzzle: In your example you're binding to a viewmodel property. Now I want it to bind to the correct object in the observable array the template renders.

Comment: I got it.  I converted to an Id property as your suggested and made the following select tag: <select data-bind="options: contactsViewModel.emailTypes, optionsText: 'Value', value: $data.ContactEmailTypeId, optionsValue: 'Id'"></select>

Comment: I am not sure I follow this answer,.....selectedOptions is used in multi select case. My case is similar to this question, only one value can be selected....why I do need selectedOptions?

Answer (score 0):

It's tricky without seeing your viewModel but one thing apparent is that you have qualified your options value (`options: contactsViewModel.emailTypes`) but not your 'value' (`value: EmailType`). Do you need to add the path to EmailType eg. `value: contactsViewModel.EmailType` ??

Also can you confirm that `EmailType` is the same type of object that is in your `emailTypes` collection

Comment: Confirmed. It's the same type. Please see my additions.